# Wy does NSUserDefaults objectForKey method, returns a string with "0" and not nil?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults

Wy does NSUserDefaults objectForKey method, returns a string with "0" and not nil?

Documentation states,

> Return Value
>   The object associated with the specified key, or nil if the key was
>   not found.

```
NSDate * date = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:OVERTIME_RATE_MARKER];

    if (date) {
      //something
    }
```

The conditional statement above, always executes, because if the object is not found, it's returning an object of class: __NSCFString with "0". When it should be returning "nil"

I can of course, test the string for "0". But I don't really want to do that.

I also tried to use ID for type. I keep getting a __NSCFString with "0".

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: What makes you think that key isn't set in your preferences? I'm 100% certain that API is not returning `@"0"` when the key doesn't exist.

Comment: AH! ... Your question "What makes you think that key isn't set in your preferences?" Was an eye opener. I was setting that key to @"0" previously in another controller, yes! I overlooked that ... So much time with this ... Thank you so much Sir! Appreciated =)

Comment: Glad to be of service. I reproduced my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This API definitely returns `nil` when the key doesn't exist. Either the key was already set in your preferences, or you're setting it to `@"0"` somewhere else in your code before this code that reads it.